# How to access remote MySQL database from Heroku?

Tags: mysql, heroku, ip, remote-access, static-ip-address

We have a legacy application running in a shared hosting service (JustHost).  Due to which I am not able to write any newer technology apps easily.

I have created a test heroku app to talk to the MySQL database that is in the remote server.  I have followed the steps from the Heroku side, with respect to adding the remote db url, etc.

But my hosting service allows remote access only from whitelisted IP address (as it should).  How does one get a public IP (or IP range) for a Heroku app?

Answer (score 0):

You can try some sort of proxy node with a static IP that securely communicates to your Heroku app

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to search heroku addons for providing static IP? or try this one https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quotaguardstatic